# Laravel: Seeding table with several belongs to relationship using factories

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

**tl;dr:**

I am using Laravel and Eloquent and trying to seed a database and attach several belongs to relationship to one table, but I get the error:

> Call to undefined method
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::attach()

**Detailed explanation:**

I am using `php 7.1` and `Laravel 6` with Eloquent. I am trying to seed a test database. I have the following relationship structure:

one user has several posts / one post belongs to one user

one category has several posts / one post belongs to one category

User model:

```
class User extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'users';

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Post');
    }
}
```

Category model:

```
class Category extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'categories';

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Category');
    }
}
```

Post model:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'posts';

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Category');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
    }
}
```

User factory:

```
$factory->define(User::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'id' => $faker->unique()->randomNumber(3),
        'name' => $faker->name(),
    ];
});
```

Category factory:

```
$factory->define(Category::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'id' => $faker->unique()->randomNumber(3),
        'name' => $faker->word(),
    ];
});
```

Post factory:

```
$factory->define(User::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'id' => $faker->unique()->randomNumber(3),
        'name' => $faker->realText($maxNbChars = 200, $indexSize = 2),
    ];
});
```

If I only had users and posts, I know that I could seed the database the following way:

```
public function seed()
{
    $users = factory(App\User::class, 10)
        ->create()
        ->each(function ($user) {
            $user->posts()->createMany(factory(App\Post::class, 10)->make()->toArray());
        });
}
```

but obviously that won't work in my case. I have tried the following:

```
public function seed()
{
    factory(User::class, 10)->create();
    factory(Category::class, 10)->create();
    factory(Post::class, 100)->create()->each(function ($post){
        $post->user()->attach(User::all()->random(1));
        $post->category()->attach(Category::all()->random(1));
    });
}
```

as well as the same function using make/save instead of create:

```
public function seed()
    {
        factory(User::class, 10)->create();
        factory(Category::class, 10)->create();
        factory(Post::class, 100)->make()->each(function ($post) {
            $post->user()->attach(User::all()->random(1));
            $post->category()->attach(Category::all()->random(1));
        })->save();
    }
```

but in both cases, I get the error:

> Call to undefined method
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::attach()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use `associate()`:

```
public function seed()
{
    factory(User::class, 10)->create();
    factory(Category::class, 10)->create();
    factory(Post::class, 100)->make()->each(function ($post) {
        $post->user()->associate(User::inRandomOrder()->first());
        $post->category()->associate(Category::inRandomOrder()->first());
        $post->save();
    });
}
```

Also `User::all()->random(1)` will return a collection and not a model, which will throw an exception, I replaced it with `Model::inRandomOrder()->first()`, which will fetch a random model from the database.

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships):

> When updating a belongsTo relationship, you may use the associate
>   method. This method will set the foreign key on the child model:

```
$account = App\Account::find(10);

$user->account()->associate($account);

$user->save();
```

**Update**

In your Modelfactory:

```
/** @var Factory $factory */
$factory->define(Post::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        // not sure why you do this, is it not a autoincrement column?
        'id' => $faker->unique()->randomNumber(3), 
        'name' => $faker->realText($maxNbChars = 200, $indexSize = 2),
        'category_id' => function () {
            if ($category = Category::inRandomOrder()->first()) {
                return $category->id;
            }

            return factory(Category::class)->create()->id;
        },
        'user_id' => function () {
            if ($user = User::inRandomOrder()->first()) {
                return $user->id;
            }

            return factory(User::class)->create()->id;
        },
    ];
});
```

In your seeder:

```
public function seed()
{
    factory(User::class, 10)->create();
    factory(Category::class, 10)->create();
    factory(Post::class, 100)->create();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I get the following error:

Comment: Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::save does not exist.
I tried using create instead of save, but then it causes an error saying that user_id and category_id do not have default values. If I insert 'user_id' => 1 and 'category_id' => 1 into the factory, it creates an integrity constraint violation, despite the fact that I try to disable foreign key checks both with 
DB::connection('test')->raw('SET UNIQUE_CHECKS = 0'); 
and
Schema::connection('test')->disableForeignKeyConstraints();

Comment: @Loon I updated my answer, it should work now, you would have to call save inside the `each()`, not afterwards. I also added another solution where you can define it in the modelfactory.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I was busy with other stuff. Anyway, thanks, it works now!